# INNER JOIN without restricting results

Tags: mysql, sql, database, inner-join

I'm slowly figuring out MySQL code, but I'm still iffy on a lot of things. What I want to do is select the most recent n entries into threads, and include a list of tag_ids any reference that particular entry.

I've frankenstein'd together a query which works as expected to some extent, but is restricting my list of threads returned to only entries which have tags associated with them.

```
SELECT th.thread_id,owner_id,message,time,tag_name
    FROM threads th
        INNER JOIN tag_thread_xref ttx
            ON th.thread_id = ttx.thread_id
        INNER JOIN tags t
            ON ttx.tag_id = t.tag_id
    ORDER BY time DESC
    LIMIT ?
```

I could obviousy just query for my list of threads, then make a second simpler query to find which ones have tags associated with them, but I'd like to achieve this with one query if possible. Is there a way to reword my SQL to make this work?

Comment: Thanks, @EkoostikMartin, that did the trick. I'll have to look into the difference between LEFT/RIGHT/OUTER/INNER JOIN queries. If you post this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LEFT JOIN` to not exclude threads without tags. You will have NULL for the tag_name for any threads without a tag of course.

```
SELECT th.thread_id,owner_id,message,time,tag_name
FROM threads th
    LEFT JOIN tag_thread_xref ttx
        ON th.thread_id = ttx.thread_id
    LEFT JOIN tags t
        ON ttx.tag_id = t.tag_id
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT ?
```

If you want a "list" of tags for each thread, then you can use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) like this:

```
SELECT th.thread_id,owner_id,message,time, 
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT tag_name ORDER BY tag_name) as tags
FROM threads th
    LEFT JOIN tag_thread_xref ttx
        ON th.thread_id = ttx.thread_id
    LEFT JOIN tags t
        ON ttx.tag_id = t.tag_id
GROUP BY th.thread_id,owner_id,message,time
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT ?
```

Comment: This did the trick, thanks! I was expecting this to return an array for the tag_name value if there were multiple tags for a particular thread. Instead it creates a separate array element entirely for each tag on the thread. Is there any way to adjust for this?

Comment: I don't think you can do that without simply looping through the results. You can get a comma-separated list by using `GROUP_CONCAT()` though.

Comment: That's alright, I'll just make a separate query to select the tags. I won't be polling the database with this particular search so it shouldn't be any trouble.